# Excel VBA Calculating difference between two cells + adding characters if difference is exceeded

Tags: vba, excel, difference

So I've looked far and wide for anything similar and all other people's issues seem to be with numbers in neighboring columns. I'm trying to clean up a spreadsheet for my company that was created ages ago. The girl doing the data entry on it has very little Excel knowledge and is used to things being entered in this layout, so I don't particularly want to recreate the whole spreadsheet... Here's my problem haha

I have two rows of data (in the same column), there is a skip cell and then repeat. This goes on for about 250 lines, each being "paired" results but in the same column with a skip cell between. I need to find the difference between these two only, such as Test Result #1 and it's pairing with Our Calculation #1 below (within 10% +/- of each other) and mark the top cell in the pair with an "*" after the number already existing in the cell.

Example: First pair is within +/- 10% of our calculation, second is out of that range.
    Test Result #1           12.5   
Our Calculation #1        11.9   
                   *empty cell* 
Test Result #2          15.0* 
Our Calculation #2     13.0

I know to get the "*" in, I'll use an if-then-else statement, which is no problem. But I'm struggling trying to figure out how (if it's possible) to calculate the difference. My sheet also has 6 columns of this same layout (one for each parameter for X sample we're looking at).

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I find it really hard to read the whole question to understand your issue. You just want to add a "*" to the test result if the difference with "Our Calculation" is +/- 10%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick mockup I did that should do what you're asking for - you'll probably just have to adjust the column as I made my mock data in column A.

Also note that for grabbing the values of test and calc I chose to grab the last 4 digits just to be safe. If you need more or less, you can just change that last number in the paranthesis.

```
Dim test As Double
Dim calc As Double

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row Step 3

    test = Right$(Cells(i, "A").Value2, 4)
    calc = Right$(Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2, 4)

    If Abs(test - calc) / calc > 0.1 Then
        Cells(i, "A").Value2 = Cells(i, "A").Value2 & "*"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to use helper cells (was hoping I could avoid it but that's okay) but it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Using end(up) misses the last blank cell below the final pair. I did it this way:

```
Sub QuikandDirty()
            Dim r As Range
            For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("a").Cells, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) 'assume col A
            If r = 0 Then
                If Abs(r.Offset(-2, 0) - r.Offset(-1, 0)) > (r.Offset(-2, 0) / 10) Then
                   r.Offset(-2, 0).Formula = CStr(r.Offset(-2, 0).Formula) & "*"
                End If
            End If
            Next r
            End Sub
```

Comment: The last blank cell is just a spacer, though, isn't it?

Comment: Yes the last cell is just a spacer cell.